# Apache2: proxying all except one single file

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, man-in-the-middle

I have a problem with MSDN Academy that they didn't solve. Unfortunately, the ISO image of Windows Server 2008 on **their** servers is misnamed. By using Wireshark, I found that the downloader erroneously tries to download a file that starts with `iita_windows_...`. Guessing the downloader was wrong, I tried to wget the file that starts with `ita_windows` and got a copy on my server.

Unfortunately, these are compressed/encrypted in the SDC format. I read lots of articles telling it's difficult or almost impossible to break them, while I contacted MSDN but they didn't solve the problem yet.

So I wanted to try some kind of a *man-in-the-middle* attack to my computer using my server. I altered `hosts` file on my Windows machine to point to my server with Apache 2 with mod_proxy. What I want to do is:

1. All requests to http://msdn63.e-academy.com are proxied to the real msdn63.e-academy.com (currently works)
2. Requests for http://msdn63.e-academy.com/MSDNAA/ITALIAN/**i**ita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc are handled by Apache, downloading the local copy, **OR** get proxied http://msdn63.e-academy.com/MSDNAA/ITALIAN/ita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc

The following is my current Apache virtual host configuration

```
ServerName msdn63.e-academy.com

Alias /MSDNAA/ITALIAN/iita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc /home/djechelon/ita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc
Alias /MSDNAA/ITALIAN/ita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc /home/djechelon/ita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc

ProxyPass / http://msdn63.e-academy.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://msdn63.e-academy.com/
```

I did censor part of the file name to avoid people download the file without a license (I own one from MSDN Academy)

I don't know why it doesn't work. Should the `Alias` directive override the `ProxyPass`?

Thank you in advance. I need that Windows Server, it's 2 months I contacted support but they didn't fix the downloader program :(

I can't try a warez because I think the license won't match the edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ProxyPass PATH !

ProxyPass /MSDNAA/ITALIAN/iita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc !
ProxyPass /MSDNAA/ITALIAN/ita_windows_server_2008_r2[censored].sdc !

This is per http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200404.mbox/%3CPine.WNT.4.58.0404191022270.2104@HEC-4949%3E linking to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Comment: Should I map ALIAS from /MSDNAA/ITALIAN to /home/djechelon first? Or just add the lines?

Comment: OK seems that they detected the proxy and stopped download. But I can type the URL from my local machine! Accepted as it solves the specific problem. I'll try to remove x-forwarded headers